# Find all Input of a Simulink model Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a System which looks like this :

[image]

And i would like to know if it's possible to retrieve a list of all `input` or `output` of this model to after that `add_line` between `input` and `output`.

I tried `find_system()` with `'BlockType'` but returned empty cell array.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: The model you show doesn't have any inputs or outputs (i.e. `Inport` and `Outport` blocks at the highest level.)  Do you mean that you want the inputs and outputs of every `Subsystem` in the model?  Or for every block in the model?  Or something else?  Also, please clarify what you mean by `to after that add_line between input and output.`, as its written, that sentence doesn't make any sense.  It would also be helpful if you show exactly how you are using `find_system` rather than making us guess.

Comment: Ok my bad i thought i linked a picture without links. I would like to retrieve ports of this Model (`On_Off, Stop_Go`). And then use `add_line` to connect all Subsystem.